# If a div has height or a class exists then add the class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to add an "or" statement to a script. If the .content is greater than 245px or the div.content has a .landing-no-display anywhere inside it, then add the class .show to .more.

The way I have it below doesn't work correctly... the class .show is always getting applied.

```
if ($('.importantNotice .content').height() >= 245 || ($('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display'))) {
  $('.importantNotice .more').addClass("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all use variables to make jQuery more efficient (don't use one selector twice) and use jQuery Tree Traversal methods for DOM navigation e.g. `find()` `next()` etc instead of using complex css selectors

> Tree Traversals: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/
>
> Selectors Efficiency: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

in your case `$('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display')` will always return true, as it returns jQuery object which will be coerced to true inside `if` condition.

you need to use `.length` property of that object to ensure no elements found.

```
var $importantNotice = $('.importantNotice'),
    $importantNoticeContent = $importantNotice.find('.content'),
    $importantNoticeMore = $importantNotice.find('.more');

if ($importantNoticeContent.height() >= 245 ||$importantNoticeContent.find('.landing-no-display').length) {
    $importantNoticeMore.addClass("show");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @godblessstrawberry. I think the .hasClass must specify the item to check. In my case I want to know if the class .landing-no-display exists anywhere inside, as a descendant of .content without specifying the item it is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `length` property of the second jQuery object. At the moment it will always equate to true due to the jQuery object being coerced to a boolean. Try this:

```
if ($('.importantNotice .content').height() >= 245 || $('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display').length) {
  $('.importantNotice .more').addClass("show");
}
```